# How can I fix an "undefined method length' for #<Enumerator:" error?

Tags: ruby

I have this gem installed - https://github.com/pluskid/rmmseg-cpp.

(Documentation: http://rmmseg-cpp.rubyforge.org/)

When I try to run this sample command: `$echo "我们都喜欢用 Ruby" | rmmseg`

I get:

```
/Users/webmagnets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@blt/gems/rmmseg-0.1.6/lib/rmmseg/algorithm.rb:24:in `next_token': undefined method `length' for #<Enumerator: "我们都喜欢用 Ruby\n":each_char> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/webmagnets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@blt/gems/rmmseg-0.1.6/lib/rmmseg/algorithm.rb:44:in `segment'
    from /Users/webmagnets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@blt/gems/rmmseg-0.1.6/lib/rmmseg.rb:12:in `segment'
    from /Users/webmagnets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@blt/gems/rmmseg-0.1.6/bin/rmmseg:65:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/webmagnets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@blt/bin/rmmseg:23:in `load'
    from /Users/webmagnets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@blt/bin/rmmseg:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using rmmseg instead of rmmseg-cpp.